# Commenting on questions 50 points?

Tags: discussion

Why do I need 50 points to comment on something but I can post an entire answer?  I need to tell a guy to up the framerate, that's it.  There's been 5 things today I couldn't help with because it's not an entire answer.

Ridiculous.

Also, why is StackOverflow 91 points, not the same as the rest saying 21?

Comment: “Why do I need 50 points to comment on something but I can post an entire answer?” - The real question, why do you want to submit a comment, if you can answer the question?  “There's been 5 things today I couldn't help with because it's not an entire answer.” - Sounds like even if you were to submit your comment it would be flagged as “no longer needed”. Ironically if you just submitted answers you would earn reputation required to submit a comment. 50 reputation is all you need to submit a comment

Comment: But I can comment on this comment.  Yeah, okay then.  If I answer the question with:  Change framerate to 30.  Then I'll get yelled at for that, too.

Comment: Comments are a privilege you earn by proving you can use the normal features of the site without making everything worse. If your "answer" is nothing more than "Change framerate to 30" then you are missing out information on *how* to do it, and *why* that solves the problem. [Comments should primarily be to request or give clarification](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment), not as "I can't be bothered to write a proper answer"

Comment: "Comments are a privilege you earn by proving you can use the normal features of the site without making everything worse. If your "answer" is nothing more than "Change framerate to 30" then you are missing out information on how to do it, and why that solves the problem. Comments should primarily be to request or give clarification, not as "I can't be bothered to write a proper answer" – Mokubai" Thank's for 100% making my point.  Once I "answer enough things" I'll be good enough to make a simple reference.  Alright, then.

Comment: @J.Cravens - No; If you submit answers through comments, they will be flagged and deleted, just answer questions.  If you submit comments as an answer, they also will be deleted, so I go back to the first statement just answer the question. Unless you are asking for clarification, in order to submit an answer, you are likely using comments improperly.  SO and SU reputation is separate.

Comment: Right.  So what I wanted to do was comment.  The answer was fine.  I needed to say:  Change the framerate to 30.   THAT'S IT.  No more, no less.  I try to do so and it says no.  I'm not good enough yet.  Well I do find it strange that comments are more valued of a privilege, and more vetted, than full answers.  There are answers that sit for years, no inherent value, zero up-votes, but it was "valid" answer, no matter how useless.  My one sentence was the solution to the entire problem, like 12 comments deep already.  Trust me, they wanted that info more than another answer attempt.